# Adding hyperlink to a row and displaying the specific row in another page

Tags: oracle, web, url, oracle-apex

I have two APEX Web Application pages containing the following columns:

```
Table 1:
Column1    Column 2 Column 3
a           x         123
b           y         456
c           u         567
d           v         678
e           w         789

Table 2 URL: https://example.com
Table 2:
ColumnA    ColumnB    ColumnC
a             aa         1234
c             vv         2222
b             ac         7654
e             cc         6789
d             kk         9809

Note: Column 1 and columnA are same values but jumbled
```

If I click on table 1 column1 'b', it should take me to the page containing table 2 row values of 'b'. If I click on 'b' in table 1 the output should open in another page something like the following:

```
Table 2
ColumnA    ColumnB    ColumnC
b             vv        2222
```

What I tried so far?

I tried editing the `URL: https://example.com/#COLUMNA#` but it displays the entire table and not the specific  hyperlinked row.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how:

- on the second page, create a hidden item `:P2_COLUMNA`
- modify its query to use that item in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

  ```
  select ... from table2 where columnA = :P2_COLUMNA
  ```
- on the first page, use a **link** colum type for the `column1` and set

  - target to a page in this application (the *second* page, right?)
  - set items: `P2_COLUMNA` to `#COLUMN1#`
- run the first page; when you click the value used as a link, it'll redirect you to the second page, populate the hidden item which will - in turn - be used in the second page's `WHERE` clause and display values you're expecting

Comment: Is it possible to do it without creating a hitten item? Thanks!

Comment: Or is it possible to just edit the target URL? If I edit the target URL to https://example.com/:RIR:IR_COLUMNA:b it displays only one row. But if i click on c it displays the data in row b. How should I edit the URL? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry; I described the way I use. Currently, I can't do any testing so you'll have to do it on your own (or wait for someone else's answer).

Answer (score 0):

At first page, make link column in Interactive Report and set properties:

1. Target page
2. Pass value like this:

```
    name = IR[<REPORT_STATIC_ID_ON_TARGET_PAGE>]EQ_<COLUMN_NAME_ON_TARGET_PAGE>
    value = #<COLUMN_NAME_ON_SOURCE_PAGE>#
```

3. Clear cache = RIR

Read this https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/linking-to-interactive-reports.htm#HTMDB30108

[image]

On pic I've passed value on same page but there is no difference.
So before click I have

[image]

And after click

[image]

PS. You should set Staic ID property on your IR

[image]

After Setting the Static ID

[image: STATIC ID]

[image: SET ITEMS]

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Comment: What is the report static id? Is it the column name?

Comment: My static ID in advanced column is empty. Shall I leave it blank while setting items name or should I create a new ID? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should set some value in "Static ID" property and use this value in IR[<REPORT_STATIC_ID_ON_TARGET_PAGE>]EQ_<COLUMN_NAME_ON_TARGET_PAGE>. Look at my screenshot. Static ID of my IR = MY_IR

Comment: I created a static ID called MY_IR in the advanced column. When I save and run I get the following error: "Region Static ID MY_IR does not exist"

Comment: If I save and run without static ID it open the target page it filters the table but says 'data not found'

Comment: What do you mean "advanced column"? Static ID is one of IR properties. Look at answer update.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. Please find the attached screenshots. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Master-Detail?
Essentially, in the set up for your subordinate table,

- scroll to the Master attribute and choose the first table as master table
- select the linking column in the subordinate table and in the column attributes, scroll to Master and select the corresponding column from the parent table
  Now, when you click on a row in the master table, the subordinate table will display only those rows that correspond to the related column value.
  I am not sure if this meets your requirement.

Siva